# Impossible to push on existing repository

Tags: flutter, shell, github, error-handling, push

Im trying to push on my existing git repository my update projet

> **All command im typing** :

@LAPTOP-RI3QM8UR MINGW64 ~

$ cd desktop

$ cd Flutter-first-app

$ git status

$ git add .

$ git commit -am "Final Version"

$ git push

...and it return me a fatal error like this :

[image]

Then i try "git remote..." but still

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the url of the repo you want to push your local branch to, by using:

```
git remote add yourGitHubRepoUrl
```

Then:
git push

Comment: `i made that, It return me ```Everything up-to-date``` but when i look my repo is still not update